# Update Knockoutjs table

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a table bound to knockoutjs using foreach.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>BALANCE</th>
        <th>GENDER</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: data -->
    <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: Object.keys($data) -->
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text: $parent[$data]" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table rows iterate an observableArray (about 2000 items).

After table is rendered, I need to edit a row but table do not render the row changed.

How can I do this whithout clear observableArray and reload it again?

Here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r3p820rg/1/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `data` array properties observable so knockout would observe the changes. I'd suggest you to use [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to do the job of creating observables for you, like this:

```
var foo = new MyVM();
var mapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
    }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(myJS, mapping, foo.data);
```

But you need to change your markup so it won't just iterate through object properties, but explicitly specify which property should be used:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: data -->
    <tr>            
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text: _id" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text: balance" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text: gender" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text: age" />
        </td>            
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/r3p820rg/2/). Of course you can make observables yourself, then just rewrite your code, so every property of each item in `data` array would be an observable.

**Edit:**

Well, since we don't know the actual properties, I'd suggest the following code to make observables:

```
var foo = new MyVM();
for (var i=0, n = myJSON.length; i < n; i++) {
    for (var prop in myJSON[i])
        if (myJSON[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
            myJSON[i][prop] = ko.observable(myJSON[i][prop]);
}
foo.data(myJSON);
```

And in your view model function:

```
self.changeRow = function (){
    if(typeof self.data() != "undefined"){
        self.data()[0]["gender"]("male");
    }
};
```

See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r3p820rg/3/).

Comment: Unfortunately items properties are always different so I can't set them observables...

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. Now I just rewrite some code but so it is easy.